# How can I get top 5 inventory items from a django model which has lowest quantity?

Tags: python, django, django-models

#This is my inventory model. I want to get the inventory items that have the lowest quantity in the model.

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    purchase_price = models.FloatField(max_length=50)
    selling_price = models.FloatField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the `quantity` field is not an `IntegerField` or `PositiveIntegerField`? It's not clear how you are storing the values in a CharField in a way that can be filtered/ordered like you're asking

Comment: There is no reason quantity field is CharField. I can change it to IntegerField if it is impossible to filter or order.

Comment: I have used int() function to cast it to an integer to calculate total i.e selling_price * quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a number of results with the lowest or highest value you first order by that field `order_by('quantity')` so that the results you want will be first, then you can [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) the queryset to limit the number of results

The `quantity` field should really be a `PositiveIntegerField` or `IntegerField` since it stores integers

```
top_five_least_quantity = Inventory.objects.order_by('quantity')[:5]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: @AayushThapa yes you should for so many reasons. Ordering by a CharField containing numbers will not behave correctly and protecting the validity/integrity of your data is pretty much the best thing you can do to save yourself headaches in the future :) Trying to fix/restore a bunch of invalid data is one of the most painful things you can do

Comment: Noted. Will change it. Thank you so much